Получить обновляющийся текст из тега #text (<td>)
Есть сайт, с доходностью того или иного оборудования. Нужно вытащить оттуда текст (раз в 5-10 минут меняющийся) из определенного тега. Но  у него нет ни класса, ни ID.
Вот такой путь показывает:
#myUL > li:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > center:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)

Пробовал через querySelector, но выдает null


document.querySelector('li:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > center:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)').textContent



Вот ссылка (надеюсь можно тут их скидывать)
https://hashrate.no/asics/ez100pro
Нужно получить из предпоследнего столбца значение Revenue на монету Etc.
Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

UPDATE:
Получаем список токенов и их Revenue
// Находим все блоки с классом 'block deviceLink'
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block.deviceLink');

// Формируем объект revenue
const revenue = Array.from(blocks).reduce((acc, block) => {
  // Извлекаем название токена
  const tokenElement = block.querySelector('.deviceHeader2 span[style*="font-size: 14px;"]');
  const token = tokenElement ? tokenElement.textContent.trim() : null;

  // Извлекаем сумму Revenue
  const revenueRow = Array.from(block.querySelectorAll('td')).find(td => td.textContent.trim() === 'Revenue');
  const revenueAmount = revenueRow 
    ? revenueRow.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent.trim() 
    : null;

  // Добавляем пару token: revenueAmount в объект
  if (token && revenueAmount) {
    acc[token] = revenueAmount;
  }

  return acc;
}, {}); // Начальное значение для reduce — пустой объект {}

// Вывод результата в консоль
console.log(revenue);

// Пример обращения к значению ETH
console.log(revenue['ETC']);



Почти получилось, но не совсем, он дает ответ на все 5 значений почему-то:
Array(5) [ "$29.01", "$28.62", "$26.92", "$26.39", "$25.07" ] Всего на странице 5 надписей revenue, и он находит каждое из них. Как получить конкретное одно из 5ти?

@Michael, не правильно понял вопрос. Обновил ответ.  Так как строки таблицы могут меняться местами, то лучше создать словарь и обращаться к токену по названию

Огромное спасибо! То, что нужно, теперь выдает корректно нужное значение

@Michael, рад, что результат получен. Необходимо отметить ответ правильным, слева от него.

Использовав функцию Microsoft edge Копировать путь к JS-коду я легко получил следующий селектор:
// Первое значение
document.querySelector("#myUL > li:nth-child(N) > div > div > div > div > div.w3-col.l9.m12.s12 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td");

// Второе значение
document.querySelector("#myUL > li:nth-child(N) > div > div > div > div > div.w3-col.l9.m12.s12 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td");

Где N - номер строки

Мне нужно получить именно Revenue в $, именно на монету ETC Строки сами периодически тоже меняются на сайте (именно их позиции , сами по себе они остаются)
